# How do I paginate my mysql query using AWS rds-data using boto3 and AWS-aurora?

Tags: mysql, boto3, serverless, amazon-aurora, aws-rds-data-service

I am querying AWS Aurora (MySQL) serverless from AWS Lambda using Boto3. I want to query a table that has more than 10k records. My query can fetch records more than 7k. Now how can I paginate this data, on database level or Lambda level, so that I can get fewer data per page and send that small dataset to the user interface to display? I cannot send the entire dataset of 7k records.

Here is my Python code

```
rdsDataClient.execute_statement(resourceArn=cluster_arn,
                                secretArn=secret_arn,
                                database='myTestDB',
                                sql=sqlQuery,
                                parameters = paramSet
                               )
```

I am aware of the SQL query LIMIT and OFFSET but want to know if there is any other better way of doing this. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I have the same issue.

Comment: Yes @DrkStr Please check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I used the approach of passing limit and offset to sqlQuery.
Here is what I did

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    queryParameters = event["queryStringParameters"]
    search = getQueryStringElement("search", queryParameters, '')
    pageSize = int(getQueryStringElement("pageSize", queryParameters, 5))
    page = int(getQueryStringElement("page", queryParameters, 1))
    
    limit = pageSize
    offset = (pageSize * page) - pageSize
    
    sqlQuery = sqlQuery + ' LIMIT {} OFFSET {} ;'.format(limit, offset)

    rdsDataClient.execute_statement(resourceArn=cluster_arn,
                                secretArn=secret_arn,
                                database='myTestDB',
                                sql=sqlQuery,
                                parameters = paramSet
                               )
```

This solution worked perfect for my use case where I used to show the paginated list of records in UI

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way is to let the database handle the pagination for several reasons:

- The query is quite simple to write, just add a LIMIT and OFFSET as you suggested.
- The data transferred between the database and the service / lambda will be far less if paginated, thus saving time and cost.
- The memory needed to store the data in the service will be less, thus you won't need a beefier lambda to do the computation.
- Responsiveness of the service / lambda will be better as a result of the above.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)
Adding code snippet might be useful.